# Perl equivalent of Python for loop?

Tags: python, perl

Is there a Perl equivalent to the following Python code?

```
names['name'] = ['Bob', 'Bill', 'Terry']
obj = {'Students': [ {'Names': name} for name in names['name']]}
```

This'll end up looking like something like this

EDIT:
As Tim Roberts pointed out: The result would look like this

`[ {'Names': "Bob" }, { "Names": "Bill" },. { "Names": "Terry" } ]`

I've seen Perl one liners that do different things, but not this.

Comment: Your Python does something significantly different to the desired result.

Comment: Hang on a minute, that's a useful result, but that's NOT what your code would produce.  You would produce a whole list dicts, each with one element: `[ {'Names': "Bob" }, { "Names": "Bill" },. { "Names": "Terry" } ]`

Comment: Please show complete input, working code and expected output, along with your translation attempt. Where are you stuck? If you're working in Python, please label things correctly. `obj` and `arr` aren't what you think they are. I recommend `arr` => `dct` and `obj` => `result_dct` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [a `map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) inside of your data structure. It's not a one-liner. It's just normal code.

```perl
my $obj = {
  'Students' => [
    map { 'Names' => $_ }, @{ $names{name} }
  ]
};
```

I have used the expression form `map` (`map EXPR, LIST`) with a comma (`,`) after the expression that is being evaluated. The curly braces (`{}`) are the hash reference constructor. Alternatively, you could use the block form (`map BLOCK LIST`), which would have an extra pair of curlies.

```
    map { { 'Names' => $_  } } @{ $names{name} }
```

---

If you want a plain hash rather than a reference, substitute like this.

```perl
my %obj = (
# ...
);
```

Comment: _Note that `arr` would be a hash in Perl, as it's associative_ -- just as it is in Python as a dict.

Comment: @TimRoberts ah, of course. The name is misleading though, that's why I pointed it out.

Comment: Not sure if the OP will care about the distinction, but there's also `my %obj = ( ... )` instead of `my $obj = { ... }`,  depending on whether you want a hash or a hash reference.

Comment: `$arr{name}` is a scalar. For a proper LIST to pass to `map`, use `@{$arr{name}}`.

Comment: @mob yes, of course... thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Shawn note the comma after the curlies. I've used the expression syntax, not the block syntax, so only one pair of brackets is needed

Comment: *"Note that arr would be a hash in Perl"* : The question was probably edited and `arr` is now longer mentioned.. so this answer is confusing

Comment: Changed `arr` to `names` to match changes in OP

Comment: At first glance, `map { 'Names' => $_ }, @{ $names{name} }` confusingly looks like the `map BLOCK LIST` syntax, but the `map EXPR, LIST` syntax is being used. The curlies is the hash construction operator.

Comment: I've amended the answer, should be clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach for the same:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @names = ('Bob', 'Bill', 'Terry');

my %out_dict;

my @students_dict = ();
foreach my $name (@names) {
    push(@students_dict, {'Names' => $name});
}

$out_dict{'Students'} = \@students_dict;
print Dumper \%out_dict;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Students' => [
                          {
                            'Names' => 'Bob'
                          },
                          {
                            'Names' => 'Bill'
                          },
                          {
                            'Names' => 'Terry'
                          }
                        ]
        };
```